# How to map pretty URIs to individual APIs by using .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, uri

Say I want to have URIs like,
www.domainname.com/horses/italian/
www.domainname.com/cats/persian/

The respective APIs are,
GetHorseDetails.php
GetCatDetails.php

They are located under /apis/fetch/.....php

The problem I am facing is that I am not being able to frame the RewriteRule correctly.

When I'm placing the APIs in the root folder and using,
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ GetHorseDetails.php/$

I am able to do a GET domainname.com/horses/italian/ and hit the API.

Summing up,
1) I need to bind the parameters.
2) I need to be able to hit the APIs by using relative paths in .htaccess

Technically, 
domaninname.com/horses/italian should hit root/apis/fetch/GetHorseDetails.php

Any help on this would be highly appreciated because I tried digging a lot but to no avail.

Regards.

Comment: Take a nice hot coffee, and start here: http://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples/

Comment: Haha! Thanks. Erwin, this Apache 2.4 is a bit awkward. I went through their documentation and wasted a lot of time trying to understand the flags. 

My prime concern is to redirect it to a php file in a sub-directory. Initially I was trying to use Alias to map it to my file-system. But it was not successful in mapping the URI to a file.

Comment: I feel your pain. I am not an expert with mod-rewrite (which seems horrible arcane in the way you must express yourself). In the past I "lazily" solved this like this: via mod rewrite: take the whole path, and pass it to a "redirector.php" PHP script, that takes care of the right redirection. So they ALL go to the same PHP script. This has the advantage that you can work in PHP instead of that crazy mod-rewrite, AND keep your pretty URLs. In PHP it is easier to dissect it, and act accordingly (at least for me.).
The requests arrive like: www.blabla.com/redirector.php?orgrequest=.../.../...

Comment: Yes, even I used to do the same thing earlier. Direct all the incoming requests to a particular php file and parse the request and use something like explode or get to extract the parameters and match them and re-direct them to their respective apis.

Advantage: Its easy.
Disadvantage: The routing is expensive when you have lots of classes and you follow REST to redirect them to the endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

No quick answers, so I decided to forget all what I accumulated and simply experiment.

Viola, This just worked!

RewriteRule ^horses/italian/?$ apis/fetch/GetHorseDetails.php [NC,L]

Apparently the issue was with the relative path. There's no need to put anything like "./" before the name. And there's no need to use Alias to map the URL to the file system.